# How to calculate True Positive in custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I do classification task with Keras, I make simple custom loss function in Keras and it works

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    return K.abs(yTrue-yPred)
```

to make more complex loss function that i want, i need to calculate True Positive, True Negative , False Positive , False Negative

How to calculate them ?

i cant calculate them because i dont know the type of yTrue and yPred . Are they 2D array or list or anything else. if i know, maybe i can calculate TP,TN,FP,FN using ***for*** , like this:

```
TP=0
for x,y in zip(yTrue,yPred):
   if x == 1 and y > 0.5:
      TP=TP+1
```

Comment: Even if you can define a loss function with True Positives, True Negatives, etc., it may not work for training. This is because the loss function needs to be continuous, so the optimizer can tell if a small change in your model makes the loss infinitesimally better or worse. Since you have a finite number of training examples, quantities like TP/TN/FP/FN will move in discrete jumps, which makes it likely the optimizer won't be able to find anything that helps. Take a look at using categorical crossentropy for your loss function, and then using your custom function above as a metric.

Comment: the my real problem is i want precision  bigger than recall , for example precision = 0.9 and recall = 0.5  , not precision = 0.5 and recall = 0.9, how to build loss function that "understand" what i need ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/losses/) the data types of yTrue/yPred are TensorFlow/Theano tensor depending on the backend you are using.

Therefore, you cannot use a for loop for the loss function, otherwise you will get an error.

But you can use logical and for this matter:

```
TN = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 0, K.eval(y_pred) == 0)
FP = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 0, K.eval(y_pred) == 1)
```

After that you can add them up:

```
TN = K.sum(K.variable(TN))
FP = K.sum(K.variable(FP))
```

Comment: i use theano backend and it doesnt work . it returns error

Comment: What error do you get? If it is a problem with logical_and, then you can try using 'keras.backend.all(keras.backend.stack([x, y], axis=0), axis=0)' instead, where x=K.eval(y_true) == 0 and y=K.eval(y_pred) == 0 for example